# Can I use "here" to refer to time?

Tags: reference

I only know "here" can refer to a location. Can I use it to refer to time? If I can, does it refer to "1980" or "between 1920 and 1980"?

> The amount of time the average household spent doing housework dropped
> significantly from 50 to 15 hours per week **between 1920 and 1980**.
> **From here**, it experienced only a small decline to just over 10 hours a week in 2019.

[image]

Comment: The "spatial" metaphor ***here*** is at least partly affected in your context by the fact that the text is accompanied by a ***diagram*** (where the reader can imagine the writer pointing down to a position on the diagram). But with or without accompanying diagram, I imagine many writers would prefer *from **there**, from **that point** [on], from **then on*** or similar. But as a general feature of English, we do sometimes use ***here*** and ***there*** to refer to (nearby or distant) ***points in time***.

Comment: There refers to the point at the end of your period of time: 1980.

Comment: The simple answer is **yes** BUT it could only refer to "now", much as "now" can only refer to now.   *Note that if you're pointing to a point on a graph, that's totally different; the 'here' is referring to the point on the piece of paper.*

Comment: Strictly / syntactically speaking, ***here*** in the cited text refers to *[the **entire** period] **between 1920 and 1980***, since *that's* very specifically what the word refers back to within the text. It's just that *logically*, if we imagine ***moving*** (spatially OR temporally) away from such an "extended space", we take it for granted one leaves that first space at the point (in space or time) ***nearest*** the intended destination time/place.

Comment: The quoted text is wrong, or a typo. It should read "from there..." or "from that point ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, ***from there*** or **a*s of that year***. Referring to 1980 forwards.

Here and there can refer to any place a unit occupies as a unit of measurement. Time, distance (yards, meters, miles, etc.) and place.

***there*** refers to the point at the end of your period of time: 1980

If "here" is used it implies the speaker is present with the audience.
If "there" is used, that would be in writing, although it could be with an audience.

What does not work is "from here" in written text unless the author is using the historical present.

Comment: Perfectly put...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use here to refer to a point in time as well as a point in space.

I fact you can use it to refer to many things.

For example: *"Upon turning on the heating the temperature rose quickly to a comfortable 20 degrees. From there it crawled up very gradually to 22."*

*"The GDP rose to 24bn in the late sixties. From there it rocketed to 100bn."* (The here is the 24bn, not the sixties.)

Note (from Fumblefinger's comment above) that 'there' is probably more common than 'here' in this context.

Comment: Excellent additional context!

Comment: Both examples are wrong, and should be "there".  It's "here" if (of course) it's **in the present**.  Hence, the examples would be "The temperature rose to 20 degrees, as you can see. From here, it will crawl up to 22 in an hour." and "GDP has now hit 10b. From here, it will easily reach 12b by 2030."

Comment: @Fattie Agree, it should be there. Unless the guy is pointed to the thing in a real setting with a pointer. :)

Comment: I disagree with@Fattie (and the consequential edit, but not enough to cancel or reverse my upvote). Like I said originally, *many writers would prefer **from there** or similar*, but it's misleading / mistaken to suggest ***from here*** is in any way "incorrect". It's just a less common stylistic choice.

Comment: @Lambie Quite right.  The idea of "pointing at a chart, as you narrate" may be adding confusion here.  Sure, if "pointing at a chart" you can say something like *"from 'here' [points - 1940] to 'here' [points - 1950] to 'here' [points - 1960] we learn blah blah."*  Setting aside the "pointing at a chart" issue, here means now.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, you've got the pragamatic diexis right. "here" requires the speaker to be pointing at or referring to the text in a real situation. In writing, it's "there".